# How to make hundreds of get requests at the same time with axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, get, axios

I'm making a React application using an external API. But I face a small issue atm. I need to make a single GET request to every ID that I have. It's possible that I need to make up to 1000 GET requests and the problem of that is the time it takes to get all the data. Is there a way of making let's say 1000 GET requests without waiting for each of them to resolve? I have this but it takes for ever.

```
for(const match of totalMatchesWithPremades){
    try {
        const matchStats: ISats = await axios.request<IMatchStats>({
          url: `https://API/match/${match.match_id}/stats`,
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
          },
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(matchStats,null,2))
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you can modify the backend, you could add a new entry to the API where you provide an array of IDs to fetch and let the backend perform the requests for you. If your backend uses a SQL database, you can also request several items in one call: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN array;

Comment: @HermitCrab I cannot do that since the API is not mine. I'll use memoize to cache the response so the next time the user only request for new IDs and get the rest from cache. But at least the first time the user uses the app depending on the number of IDs he was, he'll need to request them all

Comment: Is there an absolute need to request everything up front or can you request an initial sub set and then some button to load more as needed? A Faked bulk read/pagination support via your React App since API doesn't support.

Comment: @AndrewNolan that is actually a good idea but it does not apply on this case because I'll use the data to show some stats like the avg of points and so on. And for those calculations I need to have all the data before I can show it to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered I can use `Promise.allSettled()` like this

```
Promise.allSettled(arr.map((match)=>{
const matchStats: ISats = await axios.request<IMatchStats>({
          url: `https://API/match/${match.match_id}/stats`,
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
          },
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(matchStats,null,2))
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
})
```

This will execute all Promises one after another and return an array with if they got fullfilled or rejected. I made 400 requests in like 5 seconds intead 4minutes

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to check out something like `bulk` routes for the API. So e.g. you can set the array of `match_id`s and make only one request and get the array of data.

Otherwise you need to wait for each request to be executed.